# Pursue a PhD in a different field than MSc

Tags: phd

I have recently obtained a MSc in Molecular Biology with research on viral gene expression. It has been a long interest of mine to work on stem cell biology and neuroscience and I am wondering if it would be possible to pursue a PhD on the field. Or is it too ''late'' for me and should only look into virology?

Thanks

Comment: This will depend a lot on your country. In France and Germany people seem to hop less across subjects than in England for example. - In terms of education, a PhD/Doctorate is generally the last stage where you can undertake a larger realignment of your subject field. (Again, some UK institutions are, ehm, different.) Lastly: If there is anything linking the two fields so that you can claim some relevant experience, just go ahead and try if you are sure this is what you want to do.

Comment: @JeffE But the field, to me, seems to be the same: biology.